# when should we call logging.basicConfig in a Python project?

Tags: python, logging

I am looking at the python `logging` module to replace custom code, but I cannot decide on where I should call the `basicConfig` method.

If I develop a module called `mymodule` which has submodules, it seems to be a good idea to only call `basicConfig` once in `mymodule`.

But if I (or someone else) wants to use `mymodule` in its own module or program and use the `logging` module, they cannot call `basicConfig` themselves and are stuck with the options given to `basicConfig` in `mymodule`.

I know there are hacks to solve that. But what is the proper way to use `basicConfig`, where should it be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call it in your program startup code; triggered from a `__name__ == '__main__'` test preferably:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    main(sys.argv)
```

and put everything you need to do that is not part of your module-the-library into the main function, including logging configuration.

Comment: It seems that you are right.The drawback I see with that method is that it requires users to know the module uses logging in order to see well formated logging. That may require more knowlege than having, for example, a debug arguments to objects in the module.

Comment: Would it be completely wrong to write inside the module: `if len(logging.root.handlers) == 0: logging.basicConfig()`

Comment: Don't set up logging of libraries, regardless. *Document* what logging configuration you can make use of, but leave it up to the application using the library to set that up. See how the [`sqlalchemy` library documents this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/engines.html#configuring-logging) for example. Configuring logging anyway is not always appropriate.